# Directory structure of web application written in PHP

Tags: web-development, php, web-applications, coding-standards

I would like to know which convention (if any) you use for your PHP web application projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say it depends on your application structure. Is this multisite? Is there a heavy need in configuration? Are there a lot of external libraries?

However, a good idea would be to get inspiration from existing frameworks (a better idea would be to use them), like [symfony](http://symfony.com).

Important thing: separate your public files (i.e, the files that can be downloaded from the browser: css, js, html, etc.) from your app internal files. Doing this, you can configure a virtualhost to secure your installation, by serving only public files directly.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [PSR-0 PHP autoloader standard](http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal?pli=1) for an example of where an autoloader should look for files, and the [Zend suggested app layout](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend+Framework+Default+Project+Structure+-+Wil+Sinclair) which uses the aforementioned autoloader.

The PSR-0 autoloader standard was created by several members of large PHP frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't think that depends on the language, just on your site design, I write web site staff with Perl and PHP (sorry don't use framework) and i basically organize it as this:

- frontend/#Here what the user can see
- backend/#Here what the user can't but is used by the frontend parts (database connection, etc...)
- docs/#Here files where i document whatever i need
- scripts/Every single script i write when is needed (database schema creation, some cronable scripts
- img/#Website images
- DB/ #database schema

But I guess is up to you.

Answer (score -1):

MVC is pretty popular these days, usually under one of the good frameworks.

Comment: "one of the good frameworks". There are no good frameworks.

Comment: Some are better than others.

Comment: @Raynos - "there are no good frameworks" - in general, applied to the entire programming niche or is that just your opinion of PHP frameworks?

Comment: @MichealJ.V. It's a tongue in cheek comment. Most frameworks have their down sides. I havn't found any I personally like but I still use them.

Comment: Nothing is ever perfect :) but if something isn't good then it's the opposite. I'd say there's no framework satisfying your needs. Did you consider creating one or modifying existing ones?